# Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi.
Both my Ubuntu and Python3 installations are 64-bit.
I'm now trying to install Tensorflow so that I can run (not train) a model.

I've tried various blog-posts, installed all the dependencies, etc. However, I am always faced with the same error:

```
> pip3 install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

and running `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` gives the same error.

What is wrong? How can I install tensorflow on my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I have the same problem with Python 3.9 on x86-64. The reason seems to be that the `tensorflow` package only has pre-built wheels, it doesn't build anything from source if none of these wheels match your target system. The alternative is: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

Comment: @tttapa thanks - did you manage to solve the issue and install tensorflow on the raspberry pi by following the link you provided?

Comment: No, I haven't tried the instructions I linked to, but they are the official instructions, so they _should_ work. Since there are no pre-compiled binaries for 64-bit RPi3 on Python 3.8, your best bet is to compile it yourself.

Comment: @tttapa I see, thanks - I'll have to take a look.